# Javascript split string by multiple delimiters for logical expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split string by logical operators || and &&.
For example true && false || true = true,false,true in array...
I tried with creating a temporary string where I replaced all ||s with &&s and then split by &&, but it doesnt suit my needs, so I am looking for better solution, maybe with regular expression or something. Also, character class in regex doesnt work, because it matches just single character, so if I use [&&||] it doesnt work.

Comment: _"but it doesnt suit my needs"_? And why is that?

Comment: @Cerbrus because I later evaluate this expression and if I change OR with AND evaluation is not the same..

Comment: ... What. That sounds like a very bad idea of doing it...

Comment: @NejcLovrencic: Can you provide a sample of your inout text.

Comment: yes, that is why I wrote that it doesnt suit my needs :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean this?

```
> "true && false || true".split(/\&\&|\|\|/)
[ 'true ', ' false ', ' true' ]
```

If you don't want the spaces, then try

```
> "true && false || true".split(/ \&\& | \|\| /)
[ 'true', 'false', 'true' ]
```

Comment: I didn't know regexes could be used in `.split()`, nice! Personally, I'd use something like `/[&|]{2}/`, then.

Comment: You can also use: `"true && false || true".split(/ *(?:[&|]{2}) */g);`

Comment: @NejcLovrencic could you post the code in your question.

Comment: Sorry, it works well now, it was a syntax error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
thesplits = yourString.split(/&&|\|\|/);
```